# AWS SageMaker - Error for Training Job Linear Learner

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to train a Linear Learner model using AWS SageMaker, but am getting an error message. I ingested the data in S3 and SageMaker, verified that the S3 bucket exists, file path is correct, and permissions are set correctly to access them.

Do you have any suggestions to fix this error? Thank you.

**Code:**

```
sess = sagemaker.Session()
region = boto3.Session().region_name
bucket = sess.default_bucket()
prefix = "s3://diabetes-ads508/raw-files/"
role = get_execution_role()

output_location = f"s3://{bucket}/{prefix}/output"

container = image_uris.retrieve("linear-learner", region)

train, test = np.split(diabetes_indicators_trans[['bmi_boxcox', 'age', 'income', 'genhlth', 'physhlth', 'highbp', 'education', 'menthlth']].sample(frac=1, random_state=42), 
                                 [int(0.7 * len(diabetes_indicators_trans[['bmi_boxcox', 'age', 'income', 'genhlth', 'physhlth', 'highbp', 'education', 'menthlth']]))])

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
BUCKET='diabetes-ads508'
KEY='raw-files/x_train/'
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=KEY)

with io.StringIO() as csv_buffer:
    x_train_subset.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False, header=False)

    response = s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=BUCKET, Key=KEY, Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

s3_input_train = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3_data=\
        's3://{}/raw-files/x_train/'.format(BUCKET), content_type='csv')

sess = sagemaker.Session()
linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                       role, 
                                       instance_count = 1, 
                                       instance_type = 'ml.c4.xlarge',
                                       output_path = output_location,
                                       sagemaker_session = sess)

linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim = 8,
                           predictor_type = 'binary classification',
                           mini_batch_size = 20,
                           epochs = 5)

linear.fit({'train': s3_input_train})
```

**Error Message:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-f75e1ed29d16> in <module>
----> 1 linear.fit({'train': s3_input_train})

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    282             return _StepArguments(retrieve_caller_name(self_instance), run_func, *args, **kwargs)
    283 
--> 284         return run_func(*args, **kwargs)
    285 
    286     return wrapper

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
   1196         self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
   1197         if wait:
-> 1198             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
   1199 
   1200     def _compilation_job_name(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
   2338         # If logs are requested, call logs_for_jobs.
   2339         if logs != "None":
-> 2340             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   2341         else:
   2342             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type)
   4644 
   4645         if wait:
-> 4646             self._check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   4647             if dot:
   4648                 print()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   4160                 message=message,
   4161                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
-> 4162                 actual_status=status,
   4163             )
   4164 

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job linear-learner-2023-04-04-04-10-41-678: Failed. Reason: ClientError: Data download failed:Failed to download data. S3 key: s3://diabetes-ads508/raw-files/x_train/ matched no files on s3
```

Comment: Please post code as a correctly formatted code block, not screenshots. Same with error messages.